# Pattern match with character/numeric pattern in Python

Tags: python, regex, algorithm

I'm trying to write a Python function that follows the pattern below. Essentially a pattern-matching algorithm is required.

```
isSubstring(pattern, word) -> bool

A) isSubstring("b1tecat", "bytecat") -> True
B) isSubstring("b2ecat", "bytecat") -> True
C) isSubstring("b5cat", "bytecat") -> False
D) isSubstring("b2tecat", "bytecat") -> False
E) isSubstring("bytecat", "bytecat") -> True
F) isSubstring("2", "be") -> True
G) isSubstring("2bbbb", "b") -> False
```

The code below is the basic solution that works for the (E) case from above, but obviously it does nothing to account for numbers in the pattern. Have searched leetcode, hackerrank, geeksforgeeks, etc, but can't find a decent solution.

```py
def isSubstring(substring, string):
    len_substring = len(substring)
    len_string = len(string)
    
    for i in range(len_string - len_substring + 1):
        j = 0
        while j < len_substring:
            if string[i+j] != substring[j]:
                break
            j += 1
        
        if j == len_substring:
            return True
    return False
```

How can I account for the numbers in the pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an index in the second array, and when the character(s) from the first array is/are numeric, evaluate that number as integer and increase the index with that number. I assume that if the left string looks like "a21b", it means the second string should have 21 characters between "a" and "b". To easily identify consecutive digits, I would suggest a regular expression `\d+|\D` to split up the first string into its individual parts:

```py
import re

def isSubstring(substring, string):
    tokens = re.findall(r"\d+|\D", substring)
    
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for ch in tokens: 
            if i >= len(string):
                return False
            elif ch.isdigit():
                i += int(ch)
            elif ch != string[i]:
                break
            else:
                i += 1
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

It will however be easier to rely on regular expressions themselves, as follows:

Convert the first string to a regular expression itself, and then see if the second string matches it:

```py
import re

def isSubstring(substring, string):
    regex = re.sub(r"(\d+)", r".{\1}", re.escape(substring)) 
    return re.search(regex, string) is not None
```

Comment: Your answer does not find a match if the substring does not start at the beginning of the string

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @trincot answer here, you can use his answer to build a regex that matches what you are searching for.

For example: `"b2tecat"` is really just `r"b..tecat"` - feed that to another `re.findall` and you will find all of the occurrences of your string.

```py
import re

def isSubstring(substring, string):
    regex = r""
    for ch in re.findall(r"\d+|\D", substring):
        if ch.isdigit():
            regex += "." * int(ch)
        else:
            regex += ch
    if re.search(regex, re.escape(string)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Side note: there are more "classical" ways to solve this problem - pattern matching with "don't cares". For example using [fft](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52775/using-fft-to-solve-pattern-matching-problem-with-dont-cares).

Comment: Ah, I just extended my answer with a similar idea as you posted this. Just make sure that you escape characters that have a special meaning to regexes, and realise that `search` may find a match further in the target string, not necessarily at the start.

Comment: The code of the owner does not search only at the start, therefore I think the usage of `search` is suitable. Thanks for the escape comment, you clearly know your regex :)

Comment: Yes, you are right about the OP's code and shifting starting point. I didn't catch that nuance. OP should have included examples with that aspect.

Comment: Thank you. Really appreciate the response.